# Where is this proof wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have a sequence such that $\alpha \ge 1$ and $x_1 \ge \sqrt{\alpha} \iff x_1 - \sqrt{\alpha} \ge 0$ where $x_{n + 1} = \frac{x_n + \alpha}{x_n + 1}$.

I want to show that $x_2 \le \sqrt{\alpha}$ or equivalently, $x_2 - \sqrt{\alpha} \le 0$.

Here's my work:

\begin{aligned}
x_2 - \sqrt{\alpha} &= \frac{x_1 + \alpha}{x_1 + 1} - \sqrt{\alpha} \\
&= \frac{x_1 + \alpha - \sqrt{\alpha}(x_1 + 1)}{x_1+1} \\
&= \frac{x_1(1 - \sqrt{\alpha}) - \sqrt{\alpha}(1 - \sqrt{\alpha})}{x_1 + 1} \\
&= \frac{(1 - \sqrt{\alpha})(x_ 1 - \sqrt{\alpha})}{x_1 + 1} \\
&\ge \frac{(1 - \sqrt{\alpha})\cdot0}{x_1 + 1} \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}

which is the opposite of what I wanna prove. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $\alpha\geq 1$, then $1-\sqrt{\alpha}\lt 0$. So you are taking the inequality $x_1-\sqrt{\alpha}\geq 0$ and multiplying it by the negative number $\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}{x_1+1}$.

Comment: Just verify your calculation with an example, such as $\alpha = 2$, $x_1 = 3$.

Comment: And if $0\lt \alpha\lt 1$, then the inequality you want need not hold. For example, if $\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$, and $x_1 = 1 \gt\sqrt{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}$, you have $x_2=\frac{1+\frac{1}{4}}{1+1} = \frac{5}{8}$, so $x_2-\sqrt{\alpha} = x_2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{8}-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}\gt 0$.

Comment: The function $f(x)={x+\alpha\over x+1},$ $x>0$, is decreasing for $ \alpha \ge 1$ and increasing for $0< \alpha<1 .$ In the first case when $x_1\ge \sqrt{\alpha}$ then $x_2=f(x_1)\le f(\sqrt{\alpha})=\sqrt{\alpha}.$

Comment: If all else fails, you could always find out yourself where the problem lies by plugging some values into those expressions and seeing when your inequality becomes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha\geq 1$, then $1-\sqrt{\alpha}\lt 0$, so your substitution is incorrect. You have $x_1-\sqrt{\alpha}\geq 0$ and multiplying it by the negative number $\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}{x_1+1}$, so you actually have
$$\frac{(1-\sqrt{\alpha})(x_1-\sqrt{\alpha})}{x_1+1} \leq \frac{(1-\sqrt{\alpha})0}{x_1+1} = 0.$$
Remember that the kind of "substitution of inequality" you are doing needs to be done carefully, and you were not careful here.